# How can ReactiveCommand derives from ICommand without, apparently, implementing it?

Tags: c#, reactiveui

In `ReactiveUI`, the class`ReactiveCommand` derives from the interface `ICommand`. However, its public API doesn't seem to implement `Execute` and `CanExecute`.

How is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ReactiveCommand` implements `ICommand` [explicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation), meaning you can only access those members if your variable is typed as `ICommand`:

```
ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> command = ...;

// compile error
command.Execute();

// compiles fine
(command as ICommand).Execute();
```

This is to encourage you *not* to use it since the reactive interface is superior, but still facilitate integration with UI toolkits that depend on it (like WPF).

Comment: I never knew that explicit implementation of an interface would not show up in the class API.